# Python docx2pdf : How to suppress the output message HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=6.0), HTML(value='')))

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, output, pdf-generation, suppressmessage

When running the following code

```
from docx2pdf import convert
convert(path)
```

it prints the following output followed by a blank line

```
HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=6.0), HTML(value='')))
```

Is there a way to suppress this output message?